# Building Tuxedo Adapter for Weblogic

Tags: weblogic, soa, middleware, tuxedo

We are trying to build a Tuxedo adapter in Weblogic 11g to connect to Tuxedo 6.5. Does anyone know any good tutorial out there that can show us how to do this ?

We found a some tutorials in Oracle website but unfortunately the tutorial files are not downloadable (broken links):

https://tuxedo-connector.samplecode.oracle.com/index.html

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/tuxedo/usingosbtuxedotransport-086034.html

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to build what already exists?  WebLogic Server comes with a built-in adapter for Tuxedo call the WebLogic Tuxedo Connector.  There is also a separate product from Oracle called the Oracle Tuxedo JCA Adapter that provides a JCA style adapter for pretty much any Java EE server that supports JCA 1.5.